# Set the Image in Grid view

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I have Set the Main Window of my Application as the Grid View. But all images are not Equals. .  I have to set it according to its size. Is it Possible to change the size and set it individually  in the grid view ?
Is yes then please tell me how. . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You control the size of the `ImageView` via the layout that you are inflating for your `GridView` cells. Set the appropriate attributes on the `ImageView` to control its size and whether you want the image to be cropped, scaled, or whatever.

Comment: But How i can Control the Size of the Image as there is no idea about how to change the Size on the Image in Grid View

Comment: @Shreyash Mahajan: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question.